# Apache authentication with kerberos, file and ldap

Tags: apache, file, authentication, ldap, kerberos

i try to configure the apache for authentication to use at first kerberos, second file and at last ldap but it doesn't work.

Kerberos with ldap fallback works fine. Only file-auth with ldap work too. But Kerberos with ldap and file fallback doesn't work.

**Kerberos/Ldap:**

```
<Location "/">
Require ldap-group <MY-DLAP-GROUP>
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
AuthType Kerberos
AuthName "test"
AuthzLDAPAuthoritative on
AuthLDAPDereferenceAliases never
AuthLDAPURL "ldaps://<MY-LDAPS-URL>?userPrincipalName?sub?(objectCategory=Person)"
AuthLDAPBindDN "<MY-LDAP-USER>"
AuthLDAPBindPassword <MY-LDAP-USER-PASSWORD>
</Location>
KrbMethodNegotiate on
KrbMethodK5Passwd on
KrbAuthoritative on
KrbAuthRealms <MY-REALM>
Krb5Keytab <MY-KERBEROS-KEYTAB>
KrbVerifyKDC on
KrbServiceName <MY-KERBEROS-SERVICE-NAME>
KrbSaveCredentials off
```

**File/Ldap:**

```
<Location "/">
Require ldap-group <MY-DLAP-GROUP>
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
AuthType Basic
AuthName "test"
AuthBasicProvider file ldap
AuthUserFile /etc/httpd/.htpasswd
AuthzLDAPAuthoritative on
AuthLDAPDereferenceAliases never
AuthLDAPURL "ldaps://<MY-LDAPS-URL>?userPrincipalName?sub?(objectCategory=Person)"
AuthLDAPBindDN "<MY-LDAP-USER>"
AuthLDAPBindPassword <MY-LDAP-USER-PASSWORD>
</Location>
KrbMethodNegotiate on
KrbMethodK5Passwd on
KrbAuthoritative on
KrbAuthRealms <MY-REALM>
Krb5Keytab <MY-KERBEROS-KEYTAB>
KrbVerifyKDC on
KrbServiceName <MY-KERBEROS-SERVICE-NAME>
KrbSaveCredentials off
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: What Apache version you are using?